# Rmarkdown::render_site() Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, r-markdown

Appreciate any thoughts on this and thanks so much for your time in advance!

I recently switched to iOS and rmarkdown::render_site() doesn't work for me anymore, I'm getting the error message below:

**Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors**

I reinstalled {rlang}, {rmarkdown}, {distill}. My collaborators do not have issue render the same code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Claire, please provide the code that leads to the error. This has nothing to do with your version of R or packages, it's that you are referencing a vector as if it's a data frame or a list. It's possible that you re-assigned a vector into an object by accident.

Comment: Thanks Phil! Running rmarkdown::render_site() gives me this error. I'm sure the rmd file has nothing wrong in terms of coding because when I pull out the rmd file and run it elsewhere, I can knit it correctly.

Comment: Do you feed any arguments into that function? I'm wondering if you should send your file to RStudio as an issue on their GH repo to look further into it?

Comment: I didn't change any default arguments in that function. Do I need to?